# use Fn::ImportValue inside a json which is inside a yaml in cloudformation

Tags: json, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am writing a dashboard for cloudwatch using infrastructure as code  to achieve this I have a json inside the DashboardBody in the yaml file my issue comes when I try to use a function `fn::xxxx` inside the metrics of the json as follows:

```
Resources:
  DashboardTestYAML:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties:
      DashboardName: SummaryDashboard
      DashboardBody: '{
                    "widgets": [{
                        "type": "metric",
                        "x": 0,
                        "y": 0,
                        "width": 6,
                        "height": 6,
                        "properties": {
                                  "metrics": [
                                      [ "AWS/ApplicationELB", "RequestCount", "LoadBalancer", {"Fn::ImportValue": "LoadBalancerFullName"} ]
                                  ],
                                  "view": "timeSeries",
                                  "stacked": false,
                                  "region": "eu-west-1",
                                  "stat": "Sum",
                                  "period": 300,
                                  "title": "Load-blancer-requests"
                              }
                      }]
                  }'
```

I tried the following, but none worked (some are not even valid json but try is free.

- `{"Fn::ImportValue": "LoadBalancerFullName"}`
- `"{"Fn::ImportValue": "LoadBalancerFullName"}"`
- `'{"Fn::ImportValue": "LoadBalancerFullName"}'`
- `{Fn::ImportValue: LoadBalancerFullName}`
- `Fn::ImportValue: LoadBalancerFullName`
- `-Fn::ImportValue: LoadBalancerFullName`

Any idea if this is possible to do? 
About migrate all to yaml is discard because we're paling to migrate all to use `Amazon CDK` and migrate will be a waste of time.

Hardcoding the name is working, but as the load balancer is on cloudformation too I cannot do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be possible to do this using [!Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) in array form:

```
            DashboardBody: 
              !Sub 
                - |
                  {
                  "widgets": [{
                    "type": "metric",
                    "x": 0,
                    "y": 0,
                    "width": 6,
                    "height": 6,
                    "properties": {
                              "metrics": [
                                  [ "AWS/ApplicationELB", "RequestCount", "LoadBalancer", "${LoadBalancerName}" ]
                              ],
                              "view": "timeSeries",
                              "stacked": false,
                              "region": "eu-west-1",
                              "stat": "Sum",
                              "period": 300,
                              "title": "Load-blancer-requests"
                          }
                    }]
                   }
                 - LoadBalancerName: !ImportValue LoadBalancerFullName
```

My syntax or intendation may be off, but I think one can see the core structure when `!Sub` is used.

Comment: I am getting `Template error: One or more Fn::Sub intrinsic functions don't specify expected arguments. Specify a string as first argument, and an optional second argument to specify a mapping of values to replace in the string` does that means that I cannot use `"${variable}"` inside a `!Sub`?

Comment: @TiGreX  edited my answer a bit, but you have to check the docs for all the indentations and syntax. Can't replicate matching indentations in SO editor to what you have in your editor.

Comment: I see what you mean, I passed the entire file on a yaml validator and it says is valid, but  I still getting the same error in AWS and yes I did the `- |` thing. can it be that AWS does not support that?, thanks for all your help.

Comment: @TiGreX I don't know of a reason why would it be not supported. In docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) they write that "You can't use the short form of !ImportValue when it contains a !Sub. ". Maybe opposite is also true, and have to use full notation instead of `!ImportValue`?

Comment: I tried also the `Fn::ImportValue` and it didn't work